# How can i put the gcc warning messages in a text file?

Tags: linux, gcc, echo, tee, gdb

I wished to know if someone knew how to put the compilation warnings of GCC in a text file ?

For example :

I wrote (willingly) a undefined function `foo()`. So gcc tell me :

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'foo [Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

How can i get this line written in a text file ? I search for an option in the man page of gcc :

https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

but didn't find anything about that. I tried the commands `echo` and `tee` to do that but those commands only catch the compilation line (eg : `... gcc -o test test.o main.o ...`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redirect the output, say your program is:

```
main()
{
}
```

When you compile, gcc will say something like:

```
a.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^~~~
```

That is shown in the terminal. What you want to do is redirect this to a file. In this case, you need to redirect the standar error output (in the terminal you see both: standard ouput, and standard error output):

```
$ cc a.c 2> output.txt
```

`2>` means *send the error output (in this case warnings) to this file.*

a simple `>` would redirect the standard output.

Comment: when I used make `make 2> build.log`, it does not work: `make: *** No rule to make target `2'.  Stop.`